# Trying to get CSS shadow on right and left sides

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV element which I would like to apply a CSS box shadow too. The problem is, I want it on the left and right of the element only. I tried playing about with

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
```

But no matter what I do it refuses to work. I want the shadow to be 10px and color of #000.

Thanks

Comment: Just a basic web search about box-shadow and you'll find information about how it works and how to do it. No need for community help. Search for : "cross browser box-shadow generator"

Answer (score 3):

You should apply this into your CSS.

```
div {
    box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222; 
}
```

Here is an example of it. http://jsfiddle.net/vDvkP/

Answer (score 0):

```
.box-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow:4px 0 2px #000, -4px 0 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:4px 0 2px #000, -4px 0 2px #000;
    box-shadow:4px 0 2px #000, -4px 0 2px #000;
}
```